# Можно ли как-то сделать, что-бы самостоятельно искался нужный метод

Tags: php

Есть заранее прописанные методы, совпадающие с названием php файлов-страниц, а так же функция, которая возвращает названия всех методов:

```
class Routes
{
    public function home(){}
    public function news(){}
 
    public function getNameRoute(){
        return get_class_methods(Routes::class);
    }
```

}

Далее идет функция поиска имени метода по uri и, если найдено совпадение, она отдает нужну **одноименную** страницу

```
    $route = new Routes();

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pageName = 'content'.$uri.'.php';
    $routeName = $route->getNameRoute();
    $errors = 1;

   foreach ($routeName as $name){
       if('/'.$name === $uri){
           require "$pageName";
           $errors = 0;
           break;
       }
   }
    if(!empty($errors)){
        require 'content/error.php';
    }
```

Можно-ли как-то сделать, чтобы require '...' был внутри метода и искалось так же название метода, с его последующим вызовом.
Извиняюсь за возможно не понятную формулировку

Comment: *"Извиняюсь за возможно не понятную формулировку"* --- честно говоря действительно ничего не ясно (во всяком случае я сколько не прочитал так и не смог понять что есть и что нужно)

Comment: Попробую еще раз, допустим некоторую переменную записано test, можно ли сделать функцию которая будет сравнивать эту перменную с названиями методов, и если они равны, вызывать этот метод, если да то как

Comment: А что значит "Возвращать метод"? Может быть Вызывать метод? .... `$route->{$name}()`

Comment: спасибо, я пытался в " " поместить переменную)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, вы хотите вызывать метод роутера, соответствующий пути:

```
foreach ($routeName as $name) {
   if('/'.$name === $uri) {
     $route->$name();
     $errors = 0;
     break;
   }
}
```

Внутрь методов роутера нужно добавить требуемый функционал (`require`, например)

Comment: $name обернуть в{} надо, так не будет работать, в коменнтариях выше, уже подсказали

Comment: @СергейАкимов зависит от версии PHP. В некоторых будет)) Но лучше перестраховаться наверное

Comment: @СергейАкимов в 8.0-8.1 работает, а ниже и нет смысла версии рассматривать

Comment: @lezhni не стОит быть таким категроричным)) Это если есть полная свобода выбора версии языка. Но часто бывают нюансы, например легаси код. Или разработка какого-то гос. заказа под Астра Линукс, где версия с натяжкой может быть сейчас 7.1 и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я исходил из идеальной ситуации, в которой автор учится писать код на PHP и волен выбирать любую доступную версию. Но вообще согласен, конечно, два года назад я еще поддерживал приложения на PHP 5.6